# Flutter The email address is badly formatted

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

login.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/register.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _signIn(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      String email = usernameController.text.trim();
      String password = passwordController.text.trim();

      if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Hata'),
              content: Text('Geçersiz e-posta adresi biçimi.'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Tamam'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
        return;
      }

      UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      // If login is successful, navigate to MyHomePage
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Hata'),
            content: Text('Geçersiz kullanıcı adı ve/veya şifre.'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Tamam'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  bool isValidEmail(String email) {
    final emailRegex = RegExp(r'^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$');
    return emailRegex.hasMatch(email);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
        title: Center(
            child: Text(
          'Kome',
          style:
              TextStyle(fontFamily: "DancingScript", color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
        )),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: usernameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Kullanıcı Adı'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: passwordController,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Şifre'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _signIn(context);
                },
                child: Text('Giriş Yap'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterPage()),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Kayıt Ol'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

register.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/login.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController birthDateController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController confirmPasswordController =
      TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
        title: const Center(
            child: Text(
          'Kome',
          style:
              TextStyle(fontFamily: "DancingScript", color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
        )),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _buildTextField(emailController, 'E-posta'),
            _buildTextField(usernameController, 'Kullanıcı Adı'),
            _buildTextField(birthDateController, 'Doğum Tarihi'),
            _buildTextField(passwordController, 'Şifre', obscureText: true),
            _buildTextField(
              confirmPasswordController,
              'Şifreyi Tekrar Girin',
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _handleRegistration(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Kayıt Ol'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextField(
    TextEditingController controller,
    String labelText, {
    bool obscureText = false,
  }) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      obscureText: obscureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: labelText),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handleRegistration(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );

      // E-posta doğrulama e-postasını gönder
      await userCredential.user!.sendEmailVerification();

      await saveUserInformation(
        userCredential.user!.uid,
        usernameController.text,
        emailController.text,
        birthDateController.text,
      );

      _showSuccessDialog(context);
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print('Kayıt Hatası: $e');
      print('Stack Trace: $stackTrace');
      _showErrorDialog(
        context,
        'Hata',
        'Bir hata oluştu.',
        '$e\n\nStack Trace: $stackTrace',
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> saveUserInformation(
    String userId,
    String username,
    String email,
    String birthDate,
  ) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).set({
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'birthDate': birthDate,
      'totalLikes': 0, // İlk başta beğeni sayısı 0 olarak ayarlanır
      'totalComments': 0, // İlk başta yorum sayısı 0 olarak ayarlanır
    });

    print('Saved Username: $username');
    print('Saved Email: $email');
    print('Saved Birth Date: $birthDate');
  }

  Future<void> _showSuccessDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Başarılı'),
          content: const Text('Kayıt başarıyla tamamlandı.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Dialog'u kapat
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Tamam'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showErrorDialog(
      BuildContext context, String title, String content, dynamic error) async {
    await showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(title),
          content: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(content),
              if (error != null) const SizedBox(height: 10),
              if (error != null) Text('Hata Detayı: $error'),
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Dialog'u kapat
              },
              child: const Text('Tamam'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In this code, when I come to my home page and share a post,

> I/FirebaseAuth( 9310): Logging in as kullanici_email with empty reCAPTCHA token W/System ( 9310): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 9310): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed. E/RecaptchaCallWrapper( 9310): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The email address is badly formatted. I/flutter ( 9310): Hata: [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.

I'm getting this errors. What should I do?

```
Future<User?> _signIn() async { try { UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email: 'your_email@example.com', // E-posta adresinizi buraya ekleyin password: 'your_password', // Şifrenizi buraya ekleyin ); User? user = userCredential.user; return user; } catch (e) { print('Hata: $e'); return null; } }
```

I tried this way too but still the same problem.I tried this way too but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't initialize Firebase first put this line inside your **main.dart**

```
runApp() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(// your main widget );
}
```

After you've configured all the necessary configurations.
Then, add these lines of code to your manifest

1. Add Internet permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2. And inside the application tag add these two lines of code for unencrypted HTTP and allowing HTTP connections.

```
   <application
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

In app/build.gradle change these lines of code

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"


}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 33

  defaultConfig {
  minSdkVersion 22
  targetSdkVersion 33
   multiDexEnabled true

    }
}
```

In android/build.gradle change these lines of code

```
  dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

    }
```

Worked for me.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't happen

Comment: Where exactly should I add these? Maybe I'm adding them in the wrong place.

Comment: I've given a descriptive answer now. Check this out. If you follow the instructions it will work.